# how to manipulate data from text to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have text file data.txt like this:

> ```
> Name male  female
> bayu 1 0
> jonson 1 0
> anna 0 1
> ```

i have try to convert this file using pandas python

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('data.txt')
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

I want to get results data.csv like this:

> ```
> Gender name
> bayu male
> jonson male
> Anna  Female
> ```

what should i do?

Comment: please accept the answer which best suits you that way it get flushed from the unanswered queue and helps other who are looking for same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply can be done with replace and rename ..

### DataFrame:

```
>>> df
    Name  female  male
0   bayu       0     1
1  jason       0     1
2   anna       1     0
```

### Result:

```
>>> df.replace({ 0: "male", 1: "Female"}).drop(columns={'male'}).rename(columns={'female': 'Gender'})
    Name  Gender
0   bayu    male
1  jason    male
2   anna  Female
```

saving dataframe to csv..

```
>>> df = df.replace({ 0: "male", 1: "Female"}).drop(columns {'male'}).rename(columns={'female': 'Gender'})
>>> df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

Your CSV will be looks like below with comma delimited ..

```
$ cat data.csv
Name,Gender
bayu,male
jason,male
anna,Female
```

Or, Just with `idxmax` and `df.assign`  to assign back the values to nw columns altogether.

```
>>> df.assign(Gender = df[['male','female']].idxmax(axis=1)).drop(columns={'male', 'female'})
    Name  Gender
0   bayu    male
1  jason    male
2   anna  female
```

2) Another way around creating a function and then using `apply` method.

```
 def setval(col):
   col = str(col)
   if col.startswith('0'):
     return  'Male'
   if col.startswith('1'):
     return  'Female'


>>> df.assign(Gender = df[ 'female'].apply(setval)).drop({"female", "male"}, axis=1)
    Name  Gender
0   bayu    Male
1  jason    Male
2   anna  Female
```

### 3) Just for the sake of posterity ..

You can create a dict and then map the dict against one of the column assign the new values to a new column with `df.assign`further dropping the un-desired columns.

Here, yo can use either `map` or `replace` method at your ease ..

```
>>> newVal = {0:'Male', 1: 'Female'}   # dictionary paired with key, values
```

a) in the below example `axis=1` represents the column which is newer method.

```
>>> df.assign(Gender=df.female.map(newVal)).drop({'male', 'female'},axis=1)
    Name  Gender
0   bayu    Male
1  jason    Male
2   anna  Female
```

b) while in the below example we are explicitly mentioning it to be applied on the column which is old method.

```
>>> df.assign(Gender=df.female.map(newVal)).drop(columns={'male', 'female'})
    Name  Gender
0   bayu    Male
1  jason    Male
2   anna  Female
```

With `.replace`

```
>>> df.assign(Gender=df.female.replace(newVal)).drop({'male', 'female'},axis=1)
    Name  Gender
0   bayu    Male
1  jason    Male
2   anna  Female
```

Comment: Thanks @Joe  for appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
df['Gender'] = np.where(df['male'].eq(1), 'male', 'female')
df = df.drop(columns={'male', 'female'})
df.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)
```

```py
    Name    Gender
0   bayu    male
1   jonson  male
2   anna    female
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `idxmax()` before to save to `csv`:

```
df['Gender'] = df[['male', 'female']].idxmax(axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=['male', 'female'])
```